# killing a process at a particular port

Tags: node.js, express

I am using expressJS and have set up the server and used forever option

I am trying to kill a process i started using

```
forever start app.js
```

I am using the port `7006`

**I have used** ::

- `fuser -k 7006/tcp`
- `netstat -plten |grep 7006` ..... then i used `kill -9 7392`

Also I used `sudo ssh myip fuser -k 7006/tcp`
I got reply as public key

Still I am not able to kill the process running at a particular port (7006)

Comment: Your question was a mess. I've cleaned it a little but please don't be lazy. You'll get better answers if you write a well formatted question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ forever stopAll
```

`kill`ing the proccess won't necessarily work as `forever` will keep spawning it on you :)

hth,
aaron

Answer (score 1):

The point of using a service like Forever is to restart the application if goes by any means.
It will automatically launch again the application on the same process even if you kill the process running on 7006..

You have to kill the forever process and not the process running on 7006.

```
ps -ef | grep forever
```

you will get the output below..

```
harry@joker:~/git/mean|master ⇒  ps -ef |grep forever
  501  4259     1   0 12:57AM ??         0:00.27 /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/monitor server.js
  501  4327  3327   0 12:58AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep forever
harry@joker:~/git/mean|master ⇒
```

kill the process with the pid 4259

To clear the all see the below output..

```
harry@joker:~/git/mean|master ⇒  ps -ef | grep 4259
  501  4259     1   0 12:57AM ??         0:00.27 /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/monitor server.js
  501  4260  4259   0 12:57AM ??         0:00.71 /usr/local/bin/node /Users/harry/git/mean/server.js
  501  4342  3327   0  1:02AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep 4259
harry@joker:~/git/mean|master ⇒
```

note the parent process of 4260, its 4259(which means forever forked an another process to run the node server.js)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This one is a better answer to killing a node process at a particular port. If you have multi Node.js apps and they all running by forever, stopAll will be stopping all my Node.js apps. But this way I get to kill the one that I want to restart again. tnx